# Can We Rotate Page?

Tags: php, javascript, printing

I am not sure but there are many unbelievable things getting done each day.

So my question is that can we rotate a generated page with 90 degrees like how we do this in pdf using either php or JavaScript?

Comment: It is not possible with PHP, but we could help you more if we knew why you want to do this.

Comment: @Fabien, i want to print a page in landscape mood which has a width of 100%, but situation is that we can't use browser's landscape print option, this has to be done on the fly from code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is for printing, you should definitely use Paged Media rules from CSS 3 :

```
@page { 
  size: landscape; 
}
```

More information [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm). I know this is not supported by all the browsers, but this is the easiest option to print what you want. Another option would be to convert XHTML to PDF using [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) which is under active development.

Answer (score 4):

this should be possible with css3. see [google sideways](http://antimatter15.com/misc/rotatedgooglecss3.html)